# Background under my UIButton won't disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am currently working on an iOS app for my agency.

The app will have an menu-button on the bottom center of the screen.

All that works perfectly except that behind the button there is now a fullwidth background which covers the news behind it.

Here's a screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FaR0.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Comment: set button's background to clear color?

Comment: what constraints have you applied to the button?

Comment: align center, width equals 50, height equals 50 and bottom space 15

Comment: alpha to zero makes the button disapear and background color to clear doesn't change anything... but thanks!! :)

Comment: Can you set a colour to table view's background and also the main view, so that we know which view is causing the issue ?

Comment: what is the bottom constraint for the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify what is causing the fullwidth background. An easy way to do this is with view debugging, as you can easily locate the view. Follow this short tutorial here for an example if you have not done this before: http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: thanks! that was really helpful. actually the placement of the tableview was a little bit wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
tableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, buttonHeight, 0);
```

It will give you access to last row of table. you can also set uibutton background clear color and use button image having clear background.